# ASP.NET Core Modify Views While Debugging in Visual Studio Code on Linux

Tags: c#, ubuntu, debugging, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I recently started using Ubuntu as my development environment. I am using ASP.NET Core 2.0 and Visual Studio Code.

While I used Windows and VS2017 I was able to edit the views in my project and just reload the page and all the changes were there. I have a simple problem now while I am debugging in VSCode I am making my changes to the views but in order to see them in the browser I have to stop debugging and run the app again.

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask but I hope someone can help :)

Comment: Over 2 years later, I have this same question and have been looking for an answer form over a month.

Comment: @BrettSpencer I never managed to find a solution, just moved to Angular...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dotnet watch run` feature to review new changes to your web pages without having to stop, rebuild, and re-run.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch?view=aspnetcore-3.1